# Efficient way to export data.xml with correct order (table dependency) in Liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

What’s the most efficient way to insert data with a proper order? For example I have 2 tables:

`create table Primary (dataset_id number, info varchar2(100) PRIMARY KEY dataset_id)`;

`create table Foreign (dataset_id number, category varchar2(100) FOREIGN KEY dataset_id REFERENCES Primary(dataset_id))`

Now I run liquibase data to generate data.xml for the insertion. However, when I deployed to the Oracle DB, I found the foreign key issue. Liquibase exported data.xml in the alphabetical order of tables so the data in Primary is executed after Foreign (since P is behind F).

Each time I have to manully copy and paste the data for Foreign below the Primary… Is there any efficient way to insert the data with the dependency order? In other words, alway insert Primary table at first.

I found some solutions from the Internet but all of them are out of date. Was it added as a new feature so that we can achieve via command directly? I don’t want to touch data.xml once it’s auto-exported. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is always necessary to inspect the XML changesets Liquibase generates. As you mention, Liquibase may end up generating changesets in the incorrect order and you will need to update generated changesets and reorder them so that they can be deployed in the correct order.

Why not export to different XML changelogs such that data for Primary tables goes into primary.xml and data for Foreign table goes into foreign.xml. Then you can use a master changelog to instruct Liquibase the order in which to deploy, e.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<databaseChangeLog  
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
        xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.3.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.3.xsd">

    <include file="primary.xml"/>
    <include file="foreign.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can we separate and export data into two files (based on tables)?